# How to refresh Action Bar menu in fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am using the onCreateOptionsMenu to display the action bar Sherlock menu in fragment. I have a requirement such that if a list is null then make menu to be disable and if present then enable and some options in menu to be changed.
This is my code

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    if ((list != null && list.size() > 0)
            || (response != null && response.messageInfo != null && response.messageInfo
                    .size() > 0)) {
        SubMenu submenus = menu.addSubMenu("");
        submenus.add(1, 1, 1, "Send New Message");
        submenus.add(1, 2, 2, "Filter by Category");
        MenuItem subitem = submenus.getItem();
        subitem.setIcon(R.drawable.img_sorting);
        subitem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    } else {
        menu.add(1, 10, 10, "NOT Clickable").setIcon(R.drawable.img_hide)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

So here when it loads for the first time it is in disable even when the list is there its still in disable mode until if I refresh it is not changing its properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are using Sherlock try calling `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` otherwise try with `invalidateOptionsMenu();` for the native `ActionBar`

Comment: where to keep the supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); in my code I kept it before setting it to the listview. and also i wrote it as  getactivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: you need to call it when you want  The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) to be called again